# How to move to the next/previous slides on a CSS carousel?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a carousel with CSS

```css
.carousel {
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    outline: 1px #000 solid;
}

.slide {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0
}

.prev {
    translatex(-500px)
}

.next {
    translatex(500px)
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide">2</div>
    <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>

<button type="button">prev</button>
<button type="button">next</button>
```

It works fine in modern browsers. Is there a way to also add prev and next arrows? I assume it will trigger some JS that will move to the next slide, but how to know which one is the current slide with this approach?

Comment: With JS you can add a class to the current active slide and pass it back and forth when the prev and next arrow are pressed along with changing the position

Comment: You can use the translate css property to manipulate slides using JS. Just you just need to translate the slide in the x direction by width of your slide depending on the slide is going forward or backward. When you click on the left arrow just translate in x negative direction or in case of right arrow translate to positive x direction

Comment: @Shreyashbhatt but if you are in the last element it will try o apply translate even if there are no more slides. right?

Comment: Yes you need to check for that using some counter in your js code each time the left is clicked decrease the counter or increase it when you move right the counter will keep track of the boundary conditions for you when it reaches the boundary either you can return from the function which is handling the translation or you can move the counter to start or end depending on, if you wan't to make an infinite carousel

Comment: that's exactly the question here: how to know that?

Answer (score 2):

This reminded me that I had some old carousel code kicking around from...2017! Wow, long time.

I had to puzzle it out for a minute. Looks like I have some resize code to make the images fit inside the container. In this case, the images are 512px wide but the container is 300px wide, so they scale.

It has a `show` method that can be attached to buttons. It takes two parameters: an int to say how many images to move (negative goes backwards) and a boolean that indicates if it should wrap around when it hits the end.

It manipulates the margin offset to show the each "slide". The advantage of this is the CSS transition that makes them animate.

```js
var Slides;
(function(Slides) {
  let slides_container = document.querySelector(".slides-container");
  let slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
  let images = slides.querySelectorAll("img");
  let img_idx = 0;
  for (let ix = 0; ix < images.length; ix++) {
    images[ix].addEventListener("load", function() {
      scaleElementToAncestor(this, slides_container);
    });
  }

  function show(next, wrap) {
    if (!slides.children[img_idx + next]) {
      if (!wrap)
        return;
      img_idx = img_idx + next;
      if (img_idx < 0)
        img_idx = slides.children.length - 1;
      if (img_idx > slides.children.length - 1)
        img_idx = 0;
    } else {
      img_idx = img_idx + next;
    }
    let offset = 0;
    for (let ix = 0; ix < img_idx; ix++) {
      offset += slides.children[ix].clientWidth;
    }
    slides.style.marginLeft = -offset + "px";
  }
  Slides.show = show;

  function scaleElementToAncestor(el, ancestor) {
    const max_width = ancestor.clientWidth;
    const max_height = ancestor.clientHeight;
    const initial_width = el.clientWidth;
    const initial_height = el.clientHeight;
    let width = (max_height * initial_width) / initial_height;
    let height = (max_width * initial_height) / initial_width;
    if (width > max_width)
      width = (height * initial_width) / initial_height;
    if (height > max_height)
      height = (width * initial_height) / initial_width;
    el.style.width = width + "px";
    el.style.height = height + "px";
  }
})(Slides || (Slides = {}));
```

```css
.slides-container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

.slides img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slides-container">
      <!-- add class -->
      <div class="slides" onclick="Slides.show(1, true)">
        <!-- add class -->
        <!-- add click-handler, or not -->
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x256/000/fff">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x128/f00/fff">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x256/0f0/000">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/256x256/00f/fff">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x256/999/000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 1em; text-align: center;">
      <button onclick="Slides.show(-1, false)">Previous</button>
      <!-- add click-handler -->
      <button onclick="Slides.show(1, true)">Next</button>
      <!-- add click-handler -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```